# Find $f(x,y)$ when $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are known

Tags: functions, relations

I have a problem related to the combination of 2 relations. I know the relation between the diffusion coefficient and the temperature (say D(T)) and I know the relation between the diffusion coefficient and the humidity (say D(H)). Now, I would like to write a function for the relation between the diffusion coefficient and both temperature and humidity (say D(T,H)).

$D(T)=\frac{e^{-4.054-\frac{3151.5}{T}}}{3600}$

$D(H)=5.128*10^{-13}*e^{13.5*H}$

Can I combine D(T) and D(H) to make a function D(T,H) and if so, than how can I do this?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: It’d be helpful if you tell what $D(T)$ and $D(H)$ are.

Comment: The formulation of this problem is too general. There is another problem here: if your function has two variables $f(x,y)$ it means that you need both $x,y$ to compute $f(x,y)$. What do you mean by " I know $f(x)$ and $f(y)$"? In other words: we cannot help you if you don't tell us what are the specific functions you are talking about.

Comment: @Tavish I now added the equations to my question. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If $D$ depends on $T$, as in your first equation, and also on $H$, as in your second equation, how can either equation be valid? There must be some relation between $T$ and $H$ that you are not telling us about.

Comment: If you can find the coefficient with only temperature or only humidity why would you make it harder to have to use both temperature and humidity?

Comment: @kingW3, you are right, but I am asking this question because I am looking at a paper in which $D(T,H)$ is written as $D(T,H)=5.128*10^{-13}*e^{13.5*H}*e^{-3151.5*(\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{315.15})}$. The author of this paper refers to 2 papers on which he based this function: in 1 paper $D(T)$ was given and in the other $D(H)$. I am now trying to understand how they combined these 2 functions in their equation for $D(T,H)$. According to what you say, there is a missing link between T and H that I need to find out how they did it.

Comment: $D(T, H) = f(T)*g(H)$, with $f(x) = e^{-3151.5/x + 10}$ and $g(x) = 5.128*10^{-13}*e^{13.5x}$ (note you can simplify the brackets in the exponential)

Comment: Thanks, @jonnybolton16! However, if I multiply the equations from my answer $D(T)*D(H)$ I don't get the equation for $D(T,H)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. $f(x)$ is known for a single $y_0$, and similarly $g(y)$ is known for a single $x_0$. $f(x,y_0)$ and $f(x_0,y)$ do not allow you to extrapolate reliably to arbitrary $f(x,y)$.

E.g.

assume we have $f(x,1)=x$ and $f(1,y)=y$.

This is compatible with

$$f(x,y)=x+y-1$$

but also

$$f(x,y)=xy,$$ two pretty different functions.

---

**Update:**

There are physical situations where you have enough insight in the modelled phenomenon to know that the effects of the variables are *independent*. For example, if you have multiplicative coefficients, you may adopt a *separable* model, such as

$$f(x,y)=g(x)h(y).$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am asking this question because I am looking at a paper in which $D(T,H)$ is written as $D(T,H)=5.128*10^{-13}*e^{13.5*H}*e^{-3151.5*(\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{315.15})}$. The author of this paper refers to 2 papers on which he based this function: in 1 paper $D(T)$ was given and in the other $D(H)$. I am now trying to understand how they combined these 2 functions in their equation for $D(T,H)$. According to what you say, there is a missing link between T and H that I need to find out how they did it.

Comment: @user793232: you should have said that in the first place. Again an XY question :-(

Comment: Sorry @YvesDaoust, I'll keep this in mind for the future. Thanks for the updated answer.